# ArangoDB - Where database files are stored?

Tags: database, file, graph-databases, arangodb

I am using **ArangoDB community edition**, I have upgraded the ArangoDB and ArangoDB client softwares, hence I can see multiple installations of ArangoDB on my machine.

Well, depending on my activity I would like to uninstall unused installations.

To have a *back-up* I would like to save the actual database files.

[image: ArangoDB database]

I would like to save these different database files. viz : **Db1 , Db2 , Db3**
Just in case I mess up installations or something.

There is no option to download the *complete download* of **database**. We can only export Collections as `JSON` as of now

> I would like to know what's the typical location where the database
>   files are stored.

I did complete check of below locations and I dint find database storage files.

- **C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.X.X\etc\arangodb3**
- **C:\Users\Prateek\AppData\Local\ArangoDB3-client 3.X.X**
- and other locations by Search function.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615754/how-to-dump-all-databases-with-arangodb (with Linux in mind though)

Comment: Reason for random down-vote? whoever voted down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having multiple installations of ArangDB after upgrading sounds like a bug. Would be nice if you would open a [github issue](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues) for that.

The recommended way of making backups of your data is by using [arangodump](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Manual/Administration/Arangodump.html) and then [arangorestore](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Manual/Administration/Arangorestore.html) to restore the data.

Comment: The Windows installer installs the binaries etc. in a new folder, but does not uninstall any previous installations. This is normal behavior and works as expected. https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/5659

Answer (score 2):

The actual default location where these database files stored is

> C:\ProgramData\ArangoDB\databases

*ProgramData is usually **hidden** under Windows.*

Each collection has its own folder and has 2 files;

- parameter.json
- journal-NNNN.db

We can also see other ArangoDB files under **C:\ProgramData\ArangoDB** such as

- journals
- rocksdb

Even though I have had multiple installation showing up due to upgrades these database files are common. I verified this by switching to different server by running **arangod.exe** in Administrator mode and then calling respective `arangodump` by switching to that location.

Note : to get the version arangodump is running for we can check from `arangodump -version true` If we dont run particular aranghodump(exe) this is fetched from ***environment path*** variable.

Comment: BTW: You can check `C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.x.x\etc\arangodb3\arangod.conf` for the `database.directory` setting to find the configured data folder: `[database]` `directory = C:\ProgramData\ArangoDB`